# Add margin between all direct children of a <div> except the last one

Tags: html, css, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm looking to add some space between blog elements in Gutenberg. I've tried with:

```
.single .container > * :not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```

However, this applies on elements that aren't direct children of the container. For example the `<div class="wp-container-1 wp-block-column" ...>`

```html
<div class="container">

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

<h2>Title H2</h2>
<h3>Title H3</h3>
<h4>Title H4</h4>

<blockquote class="wp-block-quote" id="output"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><cite><strong>Firstname Lastname</strong> – Job at Company</cite></blockquote>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>

<div class="wp-container-3 wp-block-columns">
<div class="wp-container-1 wp-block-column" style="flex-basis:20%">
<figure ... ></figure>
</div>
<div class="wp-container-2 wp-block-column" style="flex-basis:80%">
<blockquote class="wp-block-quote is-style-plain" id="output"><p>Use the “plain” style for blockquotes.</p><cite><strong>Firstname Lastname</strong> – Job at Company</cite></blockquote>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is what you're looking for:

```
.single .container > *:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```

The issue is that you had:

```
.single .container > * :not(:last-child) {}
                      ^
                  This space
```

Which is saying:

Apply a `margin-bottom` to all elements that are descendants of any element, so long as they're `not` the `last-child`, when compared to their siblings, that are themselves the direct child of `.container` elements, which are themselves descendants of `.single` elements.

You want to apply the filter to all of the direct children, not just any descendant of any element (the wildcard selector [`*`]).

If that makes sense?

```css
.container > *:not(:last-child) {
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

  <h2>Title H2</h2>
  <h3>Title H3</h3>
  <h4>Title H4</h4>

  <blockquote class="wp-block-quote" id="output"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
    officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <cite><strong>Firstname Lastname</strong> – Job at Company</cite>
  </blockquote>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
    magna aliqua.</p>

  <div class="wp-container-3 wp-block-columns">
    THIS IS WHERE THE CSS IS NOT APPLIED
    <div class="wp-container-1 wp-block-column" style="flex-basis:20%">
      <figure ...></figure>
    </div>
    <div class="wp-container-2 wp-block-column" style="flex-basis:80%">
      <blockquote class="wp-block-quote is-style-plain" id="output">
        <p>Use the “plain” style for blockquotes.</p>
        <cite><strong>Firstname Lastname</strong> – Job at Company</cite>     
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Shows an example that's pretty clear.

Comment: I had a small issue with a plugin adding an additional root div, which was breaking the fix, but once I figured that out your edit works like a charm. Thank you!